# jQuery drop down menu's height increases after moving mouse cursor through it

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my drop down menu. Here is the script:

```
function topNav() {
  $('.parent').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('fast');  
  });    
  $('.parent').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp('fast');
  });
}
```

It runs great, but if I move my mouse fast enough, so that the menu doesn't drop down fully, its height increases. I don't understand why it happens and how to resolve such a problem. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle URL... so that address the issue...

Comment: I uploaded the page itself here http://jinbirdy.site90.net/layout/all_news.html

Comment: where is dropdown menu??

Comment: on top of the page, right under the picture with people

Comment: sorry! issue is not clear yet. what do you want??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding css('height','auto'), like this

```
function topNav() {
  $('.parent').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().css('height','auto').slideDown('fast');  
  });    
  $('.parent').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().css('height','auto').slideUp('fast');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).parent().find("ul").slideDown('fast').show();
});
$('.parent').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp('fast').hide();
});
```

This should work fine...

Comment: If I remove stop(), it works fine, but I need the animation stopped if I move my mouse over and out the menu frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Well this happens with all mouseovers and a UX always hates to use mouseovers..anyways if you still want to use it, there is a technique called Throttling which will help you. A plugin also implements the throttling. What actually it does is it executes the mousedown event only once for a given time.
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

So if user moves the mouse fast over and over again it wont run multiple times..